# How to uncheck the checkbox in a clone() method while calling clone() method on the previous row of table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have one table and the JavaScript function to add and delete rows. But the problem is, when I check the checkbox and then try to add the row, the checkbox is checked for the next row. But I want an unchecked checkbox for the how many rows I will add to the table wheather it may one or more.

Comment: **Note:** `.live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9 you should consider using `.on()` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can find the checked checkboxes and set the checked property to false

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    //uncheck the checked checkboxes
    $clone.find(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false).val('N');
    $tr.after($clone);
  });
  //since jQuery 1.7 is used use .on() for delegation
  $("#phone").on('click', 'input.delete', function() {
    //dont delete the last data row
    if ($('#phone tr').length > 3) {
      var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      $tr.remove();
    }
    return false;
  });


  //use event delegation
  $("#phone").on('click', 'input[name="preferred"]', function() {
    this.value = this.checked ? 'Y' : 'N'
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    //uncheck the checked checkboxes
    $clone.find(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false).val('N');
    $tr.after($clone);
  });
  //since jQuery 1.7 is used use .on() for delegation
  $("#phone").on('click', 'input.delete', function() {
    //dont delete the last data row
    if ($('#phone tr').length > 3) {
      var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      $tr.remove();
    }
    return false;
  });


  //use event delegation
  $("#phone").on('click', 'input[name="preferred"]', function() {
    this.value = this.checked ? 'Y' : 'N'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form name="Basicinfo" id="Basicinfo" method="post" action="Basic.html">
  <table id="phone" width="100%" name="phone">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#5C85B3">Phone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Country Code</th>
      <th>*Phone</th>
      <th>Preferred</th>
      <th>Add/Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="phntype" id="phntype" style="width:50%">
          <!-- Phone Types -->
          %bind(:6);
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cntrycde" id="cntrycde" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone_no" id="phone_no" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="prefferd" value="NO">
        <input type="checkbox" name="preferred" id="preferred" value="N">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="+" class="add">
        <input type="button" value="-" class="delete">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: but how to change the value of the check box its showing value='Y'

Comment: @SnehasishDas change to what?

Comment: @SnehasishDas do you want to change the value of the hidden field also no `NO`

Comment: i got it and change the script like ' $clone.find(':checkbox').val('N');' now its working fine but the problem is i have one code that will triggered if u check the box but in the next row it is not calling while checking the check box.     Below are my script                //Getting the value of Phone Preference
$('#preferred').click(function() {
var bln=$('#preferred').is(':checked');
  if (bln)
  { $('#preferred').val("Y"); alert("value changed");}
});

Comment: There is no hidden field but i want to call by using $(this).attr('#preffered').click function but its not working.so please help me out

Comment: Its not working in the first row the value of preffered is 'Y' after checking the checkbox but for all other row the value of preffered is 'N' after checking the checkbox

Comment: this.value is working fine but its not changing the value of input tag id= "preferred" first row its showing 'Y' but while adding other row its not working its showing 'N' after checking the checkbox .Please help me yar ...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to remove the *checked* attribute from all the checkboxes in `$clone`

```
$clone.find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```